# button relative position changes after screen resize

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, button, resize, css-position

I have a button positioned in the lower right corner of a page.  My problem is 1) Firefox seems to place the button in a different position than Chrome or IE9, and 2) the relative position of the button changes when I resize the screen after the initial load.

I found a hack on SO that seems to help the FF problem (see code)...but I am still having the issue of the button reposition after the initial page load.   In all 3 browsers, the button is placed perhaps 15 pixels higher (away from the bottom border) when first opening the page, but then on any resize (maximize or pulling the screen border with the mouse) the button moves lower toward the bottom border, and then stays in that relative position as I change the screen size.

Is there a way I can make the initial button position the same as its position after I resize the screen?  I'm using JQuery Mobile and ArcGIS Javascript API (built on Dojo) btw...

CSS:

```
#mainPage{
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
}

#innerPage{    
border: 0;
position:relative;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;

}

#map {
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: 1;
border: 0;
position: relative;

}

.btnClass{
position: absolute; 
z-index: 10000;
bottom: 8em;
right: 4%;
max-width:100px;
min-width:100px;
margin-bottom: 4em;
}


@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.btnClass {
    bottom: 10em;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mainPage">
<div data-role="page" id="mapPage" >
    <div id="map">
        <div id="btnDiv" class ="btnClass">         
            <button id ='credits'   data-mini="true" data-theme="c">Credits</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could listen to `resize` event, calculate height of  `.ui-page` and then `.css("right", value)`.

Comment: I will try that, thanks..do you have an idea why this is happening? Also, I'm not sure how I will do this for the Firefox special case, since I have that extra hack in there to set the position in Firefox?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on fiddle?

Comment: I tried making a jsFiddle, and although I couldn't reproduce this error, the process of making the sample led me to a solution...I realized I made an error in my sample above; I did not actually add a width and height rule to the mapPage(aka innerPage) div in my code...when I did, and I moved btnDiv outside of 'map' into 'mapPage', now the button repositions upon a screen resize as expected, and Firefox behaves the same as Chrome and IE...Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved :)